# Capybara webkit to display all requests logging

Tags: capybara-webkit

anyone what is the command to enable the logging (that shows all the requests, even javascript errors) when running Capybara?

I used to use that one-line to enable for troubleshooting..

Answer (score 0):

In your `spec_helper.rb`, add this

```
Capybara.default_driver = :webkit_debug
```

and run your specs.